# Possible to run a docker image based on local host address?

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver

Possible to run docker image based on local host address?

If i run the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.14.0-dubnium
```

The docker container will start however it will run on a different ip address, for example:

```
1xx.1xx.xx.1xx:4444
```

So if i attempt to access:

```
localhost:4444
```

Im unable to load the relevant page because the ip address of the container is different to my machines ip address.

Comment: How can docker get started on a different IP ?
what do you see if you execute this : 
"docker ps -a"

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase that I need docker running on the ip address of the host machine, I see the following:
e405ab7302d1        selenium/hub:3.4.0   "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:4444->4444/tcp   selenium-hub

Comment: are you running these containers inside any VM? Can you please specify Host OS?

Comment: im running the containers from my local machine > Macbook pro > latest version of docker.

Comment: Are you trying to access localhost:4444 from inside the docker container? Or from your host machine?

Comment: From the host machine

Comment: I think everyone’s a little confused because the `docker run -p` option you gave is supposed to make localhost:4444 work (specifically from the host, not from other hosts or other containers, assuming the server inside the container is listening on 0.0.0.0:4444, and you’re not using Docker Toolbox or Docker Machine).  In what way doesn’t it work?

Comment: Thanks David, i have installed docker toolbox but run the command listed above within dockers cli (Bash window attached to kitematic) will this make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Docker-compose file you can refer below code Hope it will be useful

To run docker-compose up -d

```
  version:  "3.2"
    services:
      lamp-alpine:
        image: ORG/IMGNAME:IMGTAG
        container_name: contname
        ports:
          - "127.0.0.1:80:80"
        networks:
          - private-network 

    networks:
      private-network:
        driver: bridge
```

Comment: Will the following compose file pick up the IP address of the machine where the compose file was executed?

Comment: Yes it will;  
try it , it wont take much time
In above file with port i have mentioned ip address 127.0.0.1(localhost) 
You can use your port number insted of 80 type 4444

Comment: The network properties seemed to fail however the following compose file causes the same issue:
version: '3'

services:
  standalone-chrome-debug:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.14.0-dubnium
    container_name: webDriver-chrome
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4444:4444"